# is there any limit For BLE services, I have added New Service in BLE device in iOS swift But Not getting in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, bluetooth-peripheral

I have added a new service in the BLE device, It is getting on the android device, but not on the iOS device. I don't know why this happening. please help if anyone knows.

Comment: Are you using BLE Device which is based on MFi?

Comment: Yes, my firmware 1st version working properly. now I just added one new service and that only one service I am unable to get on iPhone or ios device.

Comment: Maybe you have an incorrect definition that Android happens to accept anyway, but not iOS. Check your ATT handles.

Comment: As it is MFi compatible and you're trying to support it now, then you may have to request Multicast entitlement. For this, contact your hardware provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is nothing like limitations for BLE in IOS.

here you mention that it works in android it means your BLE service is Working properly.

I think the problem is in your service calling (your ios code to use service) so please check it again.

you can refer example of this
https://github.com/troystribling/BlueCap

Comment: I have checked in nrf Connect app in Android and iOS, but in Android, nrf connect application shows the newly added service in all services, and in iOS, it is not going to display or visible. So I thought this is something another issue.

Comment: if NRF connect app not showing your service then may be some problem in creation of service

Answer (score 0):

iOS caches the services of a ble device. It performs discovery of services only once and then saves in cache. In all future connections it will load services from cache and not read from the device. This is done to increase speed.
To refresh the cache and ask the iOS system to discover the services, go to settings and manually turn off bluetooth and turn it on. Then you will be able to see updated services in iOS.